# Rust library linkage using cargo

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I've got a Rust main project and a Rust library project, both of which are housed in the same monorepo. In the main project's Cargo.toml file, I'm referencing the library using a local path, like so:

```
aws_tools = { path = "../../shared/rust/my_tools/" }
```

Now, when I compile the library project, it creates a libmy_tools.rlib file. The problem is, the main project doesn't actually use this file at all; instead, it recompiles all of the library's files during its own compilation. This means that I can't take advantage of the compiled library file to speed up my Docker container.

So, my question is: is there a way to tell Cargo to use the compiled version of the library instead of its source code when compiling the main project?

---

**UPDATE**

Any time I'm updating any source file of aws_tools, all dependancies of pw_uploader are rebuilding. Non only aws_tools. Is there any way to avoid this?

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 rust:slim as build

# Install required dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    pkg-config \
    libssl-dev


# Copy files for the library projects
WORKDIR /usr/src/my_application/shared/rust/aws_tools
COPY ./shared/rust/aws_tools/Cargo.toml ./shared/rust/aws_tools/Cargo.lock ./
COPY ./shared/rust/aws_tools/src/ ./src/


# Create a new empty shell project
WORKDIR /usr/src/my_application/docker 
RUN cargo init --bin pw-uploader
WORKDIR /usr/src/my_application/docker/pw-uploader

# Copy the Cargo.toml files for the main project 
COPY ./docker/pw-uploader/Cargo.toml  ./docker/pw-uploader/Cargo.lock ./

# Build the dependencies for the main project
RUN cargo build --release 

# Build the main project
COPY ./docker/pw-uploader/src/  ./src/
RUN touch ./src/main.rs && cargo build --release


FROM --platform=linux/arm64 debian:bullseye

RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libc6-dev 
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libssl-dev
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates
RUN apt-get clean

RUN update-ca-certificates

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Copy the built project and its dependencies from the main project build image
COPY --from=build /usr/src/my_application/docker/pw-uploader/target/release/pw_uploader .


# Start the application
CMD ["./pw_uploader"]
```

Comment: Have you tried [cargo workspaces](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/workspaces.html)? They combine multiple rust projects in a single workspace with one build `target`

Comment: (Side note: You'll probably also need [cargo-chef](https://lib.rs/crates/cargo-chef).)

Comment: @JonasFassbender Probably won't help much. I assume he wants to use nested docker containers for building the library separately, and workspaces won't change anything there.

Comment: @Finomnis exactly

Comment: How does the code recompile the library files?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman during compilation of the main project I can see compilation of the source code it salves and compilation of the source files of my library. Despite the fact that library project is already compiled into *.rlib file.

Comment: @Alexey I think more details of your Dockerfiles are required to answer this question properly.

Comment: @Alexey What's the reason you build the library in a separate container? I'm not sure cargo is meant to be used in that way ...

Comment: @Finomnis updated with comments

Comment: On your host computer, if you make a change to the source code of aws_tools and then build pw_uploader, only aws_tools and pw_uploader will be rebuilt because Cargo can detect that aws_tools has changed and will rebuild it and any dependent projects.

However, if you're building pw_uploader inside a Docker container, and you make a change to aws_tools  and then rebuild the Docker image, ALL dependencies of pw_uploader, including aws_tools, will be redownloaded and rebuilt inside the Docker container.